# Force Login after logout with OpenID Connect and set lifespan cookie on Blazor (.Net 6)

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, openid-connect, adfs

I'm using Blazor with .Net 6 Server and I have some trouble with logout and cookie after authentication with OpenID Connect to ADFS.

The first login working perfectly (I see the adfs page). The problem is when user logout, with custom logout page, where if user try to access to protected page (after logout), it able to access again without login. For a couple of seconds, in the address bar, it show the call at the ADFS and then give the authentication, but without show any username and password form. How I can force users to login to ADFS everytime after logout?

For this configuration I follow this example: [Blazor OpenID-Connect](https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/blazor-faq-openid-connect)

The other thing is the timespan of Cookies. I tried some solution in .AddCookie() method, but without any success. How I can setup correctly the Cookies timespan (10 minutes)?

The last question is /.well-known/openid-configuration. Before change from Duende Identity Server to this simple solution (code on below), I cannot reach this endpoint. Why?

**Setup.cs file:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
   {
     opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     opt.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   })
     .AddCookie()
     .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
     {
       options.Authority = "https://adfs......./adfs";
       options.ClientId = "<my_ID>";
       options.ClientSecret = "<my_Secret>";

       options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
       options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

       options.ResponseType = "id_token";
       options.SaveTokens = true;
       options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

       options.UseTokenLifetime = false;

       options.Scope.Add("openid");
       options.Scope.Add("profile");
       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name" };
       options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
       {
         OnAccessDenied = context =>
         {
           context.HandleResponse();
           context.Response.Redirect("/");
           return Task.CompletedTask;
         }
       };
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  ...
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

**Logout.cshtml**

```
@page
@model Service.Pages.LogoutModel
@{
}
```

**Logout.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace Service.Pages
{
    public class LogoutModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem about /.well-know endpoint. I wrong the servername and now work perfectly. When you use Duende Identity Server, this configuration page is the same of your project (E.g. https://localhost:5001/.well-know/openid-configuration), but without this the path is:

> https://*[your-adfs-server]*/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration

The same configurated in the *options.Authority*.

Now it remains uncertain why logout doesn't work correctly..
Maybe it's a problem on ADFS.